# r quantregForest() error: NA's produced by integer overflow lead to an invalid argument in the rep() function

Tags: r, random-forest

I am trying to use the `quantregForest()` function from the [quantregForest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantregForest/quantregForest.pdf) package (which is built on the randomForest package.)

I tried to train the model using:

```
qrf_model <- quantregForest(x=Xtrain, y=Ytrain, importance=TRUE, ntree=10)
```

and  I get the following error message (even after reducing the number of trees from 100 to 10):

```
Error in rep(0, nobs * nobs * npred) : invalid 'times' argument
```

plus a warning:

```
In nobs * nobs * npred : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

The data frame `Xtrain` has 38 numeric variables, and it looks like this:

```
> str(Xtrain)
'data.frame':   31132 obs. of  38 variables:
 $ X1 : num  301306 6431 2293 1264 32477 ...
 $ X2 : num  173.2 143.5 43.4 180.6 1006.2 ...
 $ X3 : num  0.1598 0.1615 0.1336 0.0953 0.1988 ...
 $ X4 : num  0.662 0.25 0.71 0.709 0.671 ...
 $ X5 : num  0.05873 0.0142 0 0.00154 0.09517 ...
 $ X6 : num  0.01598 0 0.0023 0.00154 0.01634 ...
 $ X7 : num  0.07984 0.03001 0.00845 0.04304 0.09326 ...
 $ X8 : num  0.92 0.97 0.992 0.957 0.907 ...
 $ X9 : num  105208 1842 830 504 11553 ...
 $ X10: num  69974 1212 611 352 7080 ...
 $ X11: num  0.505 0.422 0.55 0.553 0.474 ...
 $ X12: num  0.488 0.401 0.536 0.541 0.45 ...
 $ X13: num  0.333 0.419 0.257 0.282 0.359 ...
 $ X14: num  0.187 0.234 0.172 0.207 0.234 ...
 $ X15: num  0.369 0.216 0.483 0.412 0.357 ...
 $ X16: num  0.0765 0.1205 0.0262 0.054 0.0624 ...
 $ X17: num  2954 77 12 10 739 ...
 $ X18: num  2770 43 9 21 433 119 177 122 20 17 ...
 $ X19: num  3167 72 49 25 622 ...
 $ X20: num  3541 57 14 24 656 ...
 $ X21: num  3361 82 0 33 514 ...
 $ X22: num  3929 27 10 48 682 ...
 $ X23: num  3695 73 61 15 643 ...
 $ X24: num  4781 52 5 14 680 ...
 $ X25: num  3679 103 5 23 404 ...
 $ X26: num  7716 120 55 40 895 ...
 $ X27: num  11043 195 72 48 1280 ...
 $ X28: num  16080 332 160 83 1684 ...
 $ X29: num  12312 125 124 62 1015 ...
 $ X30: num  8218 99 36 22 577 ...
 $ X31: num  9957 223 146 26 532 ...
 $ X32: num  0.751 0.444 0.621 0.527 0.682 ...
 $ X33: num  0.01873 0 0 0.00317 0.02112 ...
 $ X34: num  0.563 0.372 0.571 0.626 0.323 ...
 $ X35: num  0.366 0.39 0.156 0.248 0.549 ...
 $ X36: num  0.435 0.643 0.374 0.505 0.36 ...
 $ X37: num  0.526 0.31 0.577 0.441 0.591 ...
 $ X38: num  0.00163 0 0 0 0.00155 0.00103 0 0 0 0 ...
```

And the response variable `Ytrain` looks like this:

```
> str(Ytrain)
  num [1:31132] 2605 56 8 16 214 ...
```

I checked that neither `Xtrain` or `Ytrain` contain any `NA`'s by:

```
 > sum(is.na(Xtrain))
  [1] 0
 > sum(is.na(Ytrain))
   [1] 0
```

I am assuming that the error message for the invalid "times" argument for the `rep(0, nobs * nobs * npred))` function comes from the `NA` value assigned to the product `nobs * nobs * npred` due to an integer overflow.

What I do not understand is where the integer overflow comes from.  None of my variables are of the integer class so what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I examined the [source code](https://github.com/cran/quantregForest/blob/master/R/quantregForest.R) for the `quantregForest()` function and the [source code](https://github.com/cran/quantregForest/blob/master/R/predict.imp.R) for the method `predict.imp` called by the `quantregForest()` function.

I found that `nobs` stands for the number of observations. In the case above `nobs =length(Ytrain) = 31132` .  The variable `npred` stands for the number of predictors. It is given by `npred = ncol(Xtrain)=38`.  Both `npred` and `nobs` are of class integer, and

```
npred*npred*nobs = 31132*31132*38 = 36829654112.
```

And herein lies the root cause of the error, since:

```
npred*npred*nobs = 36829654112 > 2147483647,
```

where `2147483647` is the maximal integer value in R.   Hence the integer overflow warning and the replacement of the product `npred*npred*nobs` with an NA.

The bottom line is, in order to avoid the error message I will have to use quite a bit fewer observations when training the model or set `importance=FALSE` in the `quantregForest()` function argument. The computations required to find variable importance are **very** memory intensive, even when using less then `10000` observations.